Is there a Python function for generating Weibull probability plots like wblplot() in Matlab?
I would like to reproduce the same graph as shown on Matlab's wblplot() documentation:
Matlab wblplot() documentation
I am wondering if there is a way to generate this on Python, either with an existing library/function or user-defined.

How do I create the "uneven" tick/grid spacing on the y-axis?
How do I fit the shape & scale parameters for a set of data?
Please let me know if you have any insight on either issue!
Image from Matlab's wblplot() documentation.

I'm ignorant to what parameters this plot requires. I can manually fit the shape/scale on statistical software, like JMP or Origin, but I don't know how to get these values mathematically or programmatically.
Initially, I attempted to fit a CDF to the data, but that doesn't give me what I desire.
I can edit the ticks for the y-axis to represent the probability quantiles, but it gets congested at lower values (e.g. 0.01, 0.02, 0.05) and I'm not sure how to increase the spacing.
Figure generated using scipy.stats.weibull_min.cdf()
Data
enter code here


Could you provide your data, please, @jflyxd. (Edit your post.)

There are two issues here: the fitting of the Weibull parameters and the plotting on a suitably-scaled graph (what used to be called "probability paper", I think).
I dealt with the Weibull parameters in a previous post: How to find the x-intercept of Weibull distribution
Basically, you plot log[-log(1-F)] against log(X), where X is the random variable and F is its cumulative probability. A Weibull distribution should give a straight line with slope k and y-intercept -k.log(lambda).
For the scaled graph, you can use the Axis Scales feature in matplotlib: see https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/axes_scales.html
Here, you have to define the scaling function and its inverse. In the code below I have done this for the y-axis (where it is necessary) and the x-axis (where it is not). With the log scales I also had to take some evasive action to prevent invalid values getting to the logarithms; it isn't perfect.
I have now included your data. It doesn't fit the Weibull distribution very well, mainly due to the repeats at the start - are these genuine data points?
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = np.array( [
3.777517   , 3.777517   , 3.777517   , 3.777517   , 3.777517   , 3.777517   , 3.794043   , 3.794043   ,
3.794043   , 3.806398   , 3.806398   , 3.806398   , 7.644151   , 11.160631  , 11.394851  , 11.394851  ,
276.418518 , 418.208069 , 1432.121826, 1435.658447, 1999.844482, 2362.467529, 2638.134277, 2638.134277,
2815.924561, 2904.708252, 2981.718262, 3015.40625 , 3341.370117, 3752.57373 , 4071.993164, 4404.442383,
4511.106445, 4770.803223, 5272.486328, 5644.96875 , 6099.382812, 6638.425293, 6657.168457, 7060.214844,
7301.730469, 8164.882324, 8213.410156, 8235.43457 , 8448.899414, 9283.00293 , 9895.339844, 10560.29395,
12111.11816, 12310.8252 , 12490.26074, 12550.76465, 12921.77246, 13284.72559, 13525.23633, 13624.29492,
13860.74609, 13943.54297, 14223.58008, 14404.29297, 14637.5293 , 14741.1543 , 14909.40527, 14973.68359,
15045.34961, 15152.93359, 15223.17481, 15546.34277, 15617.32422, 16001.65527, 16018.62402, 16057.24121,
16204.74805, 16334.62695, 16873.39844, 16906.60156, 19412.37891, 19418.1582 , 19797.39258, 20059.25586,
20112.29883, 20150.29297, 20877.78711, 21542.18359, 21747.67578, 22922.57227, 23568.48633, 23662.65039,
24897.70508, 25834.83594, 25842.0293 , 27600.05078, 27783.29492, 28904.12891, 29997.00391, 30734.12891,
34335.08594, 35754.38672, 36075.05078, 36898.74609, 36918.79297, 39244.71094, 39498.91797, 40006.82422,
44638.10156, 44844.72266, 46048.92578, 48353.80469, 51893.05859, 56338.64063, 58500.54297, 61675.71484,
63681.31641, 66556.14063, 68878.35938, 69311.77344, 69530.48438, 73514.09375, 73517.79688, 83087.75781,
85957.74219, 87765.54688, 88065.76563, 88191.40133, 92179.38672, 94987.21484, 95236.79688, 101024.1875,
102910.9795, 107818.7109, 111937.3594, 130733.7266, 131932.7656, 140752.8438, 166462.375 , 202798.1406,
214275.3594, 216515.7969, 221936.9844, 322737.5313 ] )

n = len( x )
i = np.arange(1, n + 1)
F = (i - 0.5) / (n + 0.25)

# Fit a linear regression to scaled variables to estimate the parameters of the Weibull distribution
scaled_x = np.log( x )
scaled_F = np.log( -np.log( 1 - F ) )
slope, intercept = np.polyfit( scaled_x, scaled_F, 1)
k = slope
lam = np.exp( -intercept / k )             # -k ln( lambda ) = intercept
print( "Shape parameter (k):     ", k   )
print( "Scale parameter (lambda):", lam )


# Scaling functions for the two axes
SMALL = 1.0e-20    # attempt to protect against invalid arguments to log

def forwardY( p ):
    return np.log(    np.fmax( SMALL, - np.log( np.fmax(SMALL,1-p) )   )      )

def inverseY( q ):
    return 1 - np.exp( - np.exp( q ) )

def forwardX(x):
    return np.log( np.fmax(SMALL,x) )

def inverseX(y):
    return np.exp(y)


# Weibull CDF
def CDF( x, k, L ):
    return 1 - np.exp( - ( x / L) ** k )

# Plot data and exact distribution
x1, x2 = min( x ), max( x )
y1, y2 = CDF( x1, k, lam ), CDF( x2, k, lam )

probs = [ 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 0.90, 0.96, 0.99 ]
xticks = [ 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000 ]

fig, ax = plt.subplots( layout='constrained' )
ax.plot( x, F, 'bx' )
ax.plot( [x1,x2], [y1,y2], 'r-' )
ax.set_xlim( left=min(x), right=max( x ) )
ax.set_ylim( bottom=0.01, top=0.99 )
ax.set_xscale( 'function', functions=(forwardX,inverseX) )
ax.set_yscale( 'function', functions=(forwardY,inverseY) )
ax.set_xticks( xticks )
ax.set_yticks( probs )
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel( 'Time to Breakdown (TBD)' )
ax.set_ylabel( 'Cumulative distribution function' )
plt.show()

Output:
Shape parameter (k):      0.40140859230454723
Scale parameter (lambda): 33069.587531939374



Thank you! Made-up data is fine.

How does F work in selecting the placement of the data's probability?
I was also going to ask about the case where data has NaN values, in the event a row of data never fails, but I can just adjust F & i accordingly.


F is the cumulative probability (or relative frequency in the case of experimental data). This case came from a previous post. You can simply put the F values in an array if you have the data; i wouldn’t have any importance then.

I'm assuming the purpose of using "SMALL" is to avoid taking the log of a negative number. Somehow, I ran into the error: posx and posy should be finite values, when I adjusted it for my real data, where n = len(df) = 140.
However, when I check the output of scaled_x and scaled_F, the provided values are all real numbers. Am I missing something?
I provided my data in a pastebin link above, btw

My abject apologies - I got one of the inverse functions wrong. I have now included your data. The many repeats at the start make a fit to the Weibull distribution quite poor. If they are a default value replacing bad data then it would be better to remove them.
